Start an app is a screen session and detach (via a cron job)
I have a jukebox application that's powered by Spotify. I simply need to start Spotify at 8:00 UTC everyday and have my Laravel application perform an initialisation step.
My plan is to start the application, in a screen session, so that the terminal can detach. This is handy if I want to run the command outside of cron or check any messages the application might produce in the terminal by re-attaching later.
My script works when not run via CRON.
./resources/cli/start.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Start spotify in a new screen
screen -dmS spotify "spotify"

# Give Spotify time to open
sleep 5

# Reset the spotify state (it's a Laravel application and performs initialisation stuff over the Spotify API)
( cd /var/www/production && php artisan spotify:reset )


My cron expression is as follows. The cd is perhaps a bit irrelavant but matches my other Laravel-related cron tasks...
0 8 * * * cd /var/www/production && ./resources/cli/start.sh >> /dev/null 2>&1

This is dedicated machine running Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS.
Whenever I check in the morning, Spotify is not running and screen -ls does not show any active sessions.
Why would the script work when run in a regular terminal but not via a cronjob as the same user?
Thanks.

Update:
I can confirm that my cron job is running. I can use cron to execute other tasks (plus I tested writing some simple text to a file and it appeared). I also ran grep CRON /var/log/syslog and could see my job in the log.
Oct 17 07:59:00 Jukebox CRON[2806757]: (root) CMD (cd /var/www/production && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1)
Oct 17 08:00:00 Jukebox CRON[2809479]: (root) CMD (cd /var/www/production && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1)
Oct 17 08:00:00 Jukebox CRON[2809481]: (jukebox) CMD (cd /var/www/production && ./resources/cli/start.sh >> /dev/null 2>&1)
Oct 17 08:01:00 Jukebox CRON[2812189]: (root) CMD (cd /var/www/production && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1)
Oct 17 08:02:00 Jukebox CRON[2814914]: (root) CMD (cd /var/www/production && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1)

I've also tried using the full path to spotify (/snap/bin/spotify).
Update
I've ran the cron without nuking the output to /dev/null and see what looks like an issue with apparmor="DENIED".
Oct 18 10:39:00 Jukebox CRON[8413]: (jukebox) CMD (cd /var/www/production && ./resources/cli/start.sh)
Oct 18 10:39:00 Jukebox systemd[1303]: Started snap.spotify.spotify-76bd649b-c896-4f04-9f5e-d9ef023a72e8.scope.
Oct 18 10:39:00 Jukebox kernel: [  470.862746] kauditd_printk_skb: 29 callbacks suppressed
Oct 18 10:39:00 Jukebox kernel: [  470.862750] audit: type=1400 audit(1729244340.105:112): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=8418 comm="snap-confine" capability=12  capname="net_admin"
Oct 18 10:39:00 Jukebox kernel: [  470.862757] audit: type=1400 audit(1729244340.105:113): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=8418 comm="snap-confine" capability=38  capname="perfmon"
Oct 18 10:39:00 Jukebox systemd[1]: tmp-snap.rootfs_hD7VJd.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 18 10:39:00 Jukebox systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 18 10:39:00 Jukebox systemd[1]: Finished Clean php session files.
Oct 18 10:39:01 Jukebox kernel: [  472.104706] audit: type=1326 audit(1729244341.347:114): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=14 subj=snap.spotify.spotify pid=8546 comm="spotify" exe="/snap/spotify/79/usr/share/spotify/spotify" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=330 compat=0 ip=0x7368af1a922b code=0x50000
Oct 18 10:39:01 Jukebox kernel: [  472.104780] audit: type=1326 audit(1729244341.348:115): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=14 subj=snap.spotify.spotify pid=8547 comm="spotify" exe="/snap/spotify/79/usr/share/spotify/spotify" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=330 compat=0 ip=0x70ea802e522b code=0x50000
Oct 18 10:39:01 Jukebox kernel: [  472.131241] audit: type=1326 audit(1729244341.374:116): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=14 subj=snap.spotify.spotify pid=8418 comm="spotify" exe="/snap/spotify/79/usr/share/spotify/spotify" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=444 compat=0 ip=0x73a30d64b95d code=0x50000
Oct 18 10:39:01 Jukebox systemd[1303]: snap.spotify.spotify-76bd649b-c896-4f04-9f5e-d9ef023a72e8.scope: Consumed 1.131s CPU time.
Oct 18 10:39:10 Jukebox CRON[8408]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)


This question is similar to: CronJob not running. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

please share the output of command crontab -l

Also you can try to add full path to spotify in your script

Hi @Biffen, I can confirm that my cron job is running. When I grep CRON /var/log/syslog I can see
Oct 17 08:00:00 Jukebox CRON[2809479]: (root) CMD (cd /var/www/production && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1)
Oct 17 08:00:00 Jukebox CRON[2809481]: (jukebox) CMD (cd /var/www/production && ./resources/cli/start.sh >> /dev/null 2>&1)
Oct 17 08:01:00 Jukebox CRON[2812189]: (root) CMD (cd /var/www/production && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1)
I know CRON works because I can use it write a simple text file every minute. This seems to be specific to my script.

Hi @poisoned_monkey, the only other content in the cron for that user is my stop script which works
0 19 * * * cd /var/www/production && ./resources/cli/stop.sh >> /dev/null 2>&1

Please [edit] the question to clarify; code is hard to read in comments.

Have done. Sorry, I don't use StackOverflow very often. Hope that helps.

It seems the issue may be to do with apparmor. I'm not familiar with this. How can I grant access to Spotify?
